# awk using external script and <

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

How would I do something like this:

```
awk < file '{ print $2 }'
```

where '{ print $2 }' is inside a file called awk-script?

My best guess is

```
awk < file `command awk-script`
```

OR

```
awk < file `cat awk-script`
```

But no success.

Comment: awk -f awk-script < file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do

```
awk -f awk-script < file
```

where `awk-script` contains

```
[tthangavel@ltest ~/test]$ cat awk-script
{ print $2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find out about all command line options for awk here
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html

Here is the description of option f

-f source-file

--file source-file

Read the awk program source from source-file instead of in the first nonoption argument. This option may be given multiple times; the awk program consists of the concatenation of the contents of each specified source-file